# Explaining SGD in keras functionality

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand the the [SGD optimizer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L164) on keras in order to implement an accumulative version of this optimizer. I am stuck to a point where I cannot really follow the reasoning of the commands after a certain point.

The actual function is this one:

```
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

    lr = self.learning_rate
    if self.initial_decay > 0:
        lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                  K.dtype(self.decay))))
    # momentum
    shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
    moments = [K.zeros(shape, name='moment_' + str(i)) for (i, shape) in enumerate(shapes)]
    self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
    for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
        v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
        self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))

        if self.nesterov:
            new_p = p + self.momentum * v - lr * g
        else:
            new_p = p + v

        # Apply constraints.
        if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
            new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

        self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
    return self.updates
```

which if I am not mistaken is being called at every iteration. (Because for various reasons I have trouble debugging the actual function I am guessing it's actual behavior).

The line `moments = [K.zeros(shape, name='moment_' + str(i)) for (i, shape) in enumerate(shapes)]` creates an empty tensor to keep the moments as I get it. But when I calculate by hand I don't get the results I would expect from the theoretical formula.

For example for 2 iterations we have (assuming `self.momentum = 0.9` and not applying Nesterov for simplicity):

*Iter #1:*

`grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)`: calculates the gradient, let's call them `grad1`.
...
Inside `for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments)` loop:
`v1 = self.momentum * m - lr * g  = 0.9*0 - lr * grad1 = - lr * grad1`.
Update `m`->`v1` and `p`->`new_p = p + v1 = - lr * grad1`.

*Iter #2:*

`grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)`: calculates the gradient, let's call them `grad2`.
...
Inside `for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments)` loop:
(`m` is initialized at every iteration to `0` I think. Correct me if I am wrong)
`v2 = self.momentum * m - lr * g  = 0.9*0 - lr * grad2 = - lr * grad2`. 
Update `m`->`v and`p -> new_p = p + v = v1 + v2 = - lr * grad1 - lr * grad2`.

I would expect something like: `- 0.9*lr * grad1 - lr * grad2` to come up here. Also, judging from my calculations `m` (moments) does not seem to be used so I am probably mistaken somehow in my calculations. Can someone explain the mentality behind SGD in keras?

Also, I have some trouble understanding what that `for` is iterating on which might have given me a clue what am I missing here.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue, did you find a reply?